# What does it mean for a function to be "Locally Bijective"?

Tags: calculus, functions

In my calculus text, it states that a function $f$ can be integrated iff it is **Locally Bijective**. I'm wondering what this means, since given my (very elementary) understanding of what a bijective function is, I feel like this is somewhat inaccurate. For instance,  $f(x)=-x^2+1$ isn't bijective around x=0, but I can still integrate it in an interval containing $0$. Sorry if this is a really stupid question, just need some help!

Comment: Is that exactly what it says?  I'm not sure what "locally bijective" should mean, but I can't think of any reasonable meaning for it that would make that statement true.

Comment: Probably "locally bijective" means that for every point of the domain of $f$ exists a neighborhood such that the function restricted to this neighborhood is bijective. Anyway it doesnt make so much sense because a function can be non-locally bijective in it domain but locally bijective in it range of integration.

Comment: It's not even true that every bijective function is integrable. Were there additional conditions on $f$?

Comment: Yeah, I thought this was very strange. I asked my professor and he told me to disregard this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Definition:}$ A function $f$ is locally bijective at a point $x_0$ if there exists $\delta >0$ such that the restriction of $f$ on the interval $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$ is bijective.

The above is the usual definition of a "local property". Now the problem is that the function $f(x) = -x^2 + 1$ is neither bijective nor locally bijective at $x_0 = 0$. So a little more context might be needed.

Comment: Small correction to the definition.  You put locality on the domain, but you need to put locality on the range too.  Otherwise, continuous maps to spaces with more than one point will never be locally bijective.  But I agree, I don't see how local bijectivity relates to integrability.